# Is it possible to wrap a tbody tag

Tags: jquery, html, html-table, jquery-ui-sortable

I have the following code

```
<table style="width:100%;">
    <thead >
        <tr>
            <td style="width:6%">ID</td>               
            <td style="width:94%">Notes</td>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>1</td>
            <td>Some Notes</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>2</td>
            <td>More Notes</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

This works fine! However, I need to add the Jquery sortable. This is where I'm stuck.

The only thing that needs to be `sortable` is the `tbody` section. However, I don't know how to wrap them.

If I wrap the `tbody` with a `div`, I get told off as this is invalid HTML. EG

```
<div id ="someIdForParent">
   <tbody>...</tbody><tbody>...</tbody>
</div>
```

However, this is what I'd like to do so the tbody can have the `containment` as `"parent"`.

I am unable to control the layout of the HTML, in that, it will only come as an array of `tbody` elements

Can this be done with valid HTML(5)?

Comment: "*Can this be done with valid HTML..?*" - no, the only element that can wrap, or contain, a `<tbody>` element is a `<table>`; can you apply the sortable to the parent table?

Comment: @DavidThomas Thank you. I had the feeling it wasn't possible, I did read the docs and it's nice to know that I had read them correctly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to leave the first row in place, use:

```
$('table').sortable({items: 'tr:not(:first)'});
```

Comment: This is perfect. Thank you for taking the time to realise what I was trying to achieve and suggesting a solution. It wasn't clear from http://api.jqueryui.com/sortable/#option-items that this was an option (I did look and try myself first)